# How to create a configuration class

Tags: typescript, typescript1.7

I have a class which is used for configuration purposes that looks like this.

```
let urlsForDevelopement:any = {
 serviceName : "https://localhost:44300/breeze/data",
 signalrAddress : 'https://localhost:44300'
};

let urlsForProduction: any = {
    serviceName: "https://Prodhost:44300/breeze/data",
    signalrAddress: 'https://Prodhost:44300'
};


var Urls: any;
if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {
    Urls = urlsForDevelopement;
}
else {
    Urls = urlsForProduction;
}

export default Urls;
```

It does work.  But is there a way to write this as a class?  Or perhaps a better way of writing it?

In c#, I would use a preprocessor `if` statement.

Comment: Maybe this should be on [codereview.se]?

Comment: Not much Typescript activity over there.

Comment: You can, of course, write this as a class. But the problem seems like one that is better solved in the build step, so if you are using gulp or grunt or something similar to build you can easily solve it in the build process. That way the urls used for testing will not even be in the transpiled .js code for production.

Comment: @Nypan Yes, you are right, I need to start thinking of Gulp as the "preprocessor" for TS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In c#, I would use a preprocessor if statement.

I would too. Not supported by TypeScript. Discussion : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4691